# $k$-th diagonal element of an inverse matrix $(\textbf{H}^{\dagger}\textbf{H})^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Let $\textbf{W}=\textbf{H}^{\dagger}\textbf{H}$ with $\{\cdot\}^{\dagger}$ being conjugate transpose operator. In some materials I have read so far, there is a common statement that the $k$-th diagonal element of the inverse matrix $\textbf{W}^{-1}$ can be presented as
\begin{align}
[\textbf{W}^{-1}]_{k,k} = \frac{1}
{\textbf{h}_k^{\dagger}\textbf{h}_k
-\textbf{h}_k\textbf{H}_k(\textbf{H}_k^{\dagger}\textbf{H}_k)^{-1}\textbf{H}_k^{\dagger}\textbf{h}_k}
\end{align}
where $\textbf{h}_k$ is the $k$-th column of $\textbf{H}$, and $\textbf{H}_k$ is the **submatrix** obtained by striking $\textbf{h}_k$ out of $\textbf{H}$.

I understand that the above expression must be derived from a certain analysis relating to Schur complement, but I cannot give a proof myself.

Would you please show me a proof for the above-mentioned expression?